# Why no ashrei in maariv?

Tags: tefilla, number, shacharis-morning-prayer, maariv

Why no ashrei in maariv, despite its importance?  Also, why in shacharit twice?  (Perhaps these are related questions.)

Comment: The minimum length is to ensure that you've incorporated things like background information on the topic, motivation for your asking, or evidence of your claims. Not so you can circumvent the minimum by adding an unnecessary sentence.

Comment: Why is maariv so important?

Comment: @DoubleAA  I am relatively new here and still trying to figure out how this group works.  What would you have me add to the question to improve it?

Comment: @YehudaW: This might be a good place to start: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1715/603

Comment: @YehudaW: in addition to the information in the above link I would recommend the trying to address the following question when formulating a question - __"How can I make my question most helpful for someone who does not know the answer, but would like to do some research and find an answer?"__  - Formulate your question in such a way that someone reading it may think, __"That's an interesting question, I wonder what the answer is. Let me see if I can find something."__ - The person may not have any idea, but your question should give him enough to start searching...

Comment: ...They should be able to use the sources you prove for some research. In your question, you assert that Ashrei is important. Why is it important? How do you know it is important? Why you think that its importance means it should be said in every prayer. Addressing this issues will both increase the quality of your question and also  increase the chance someone may look for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Loewian already cited Talmud Brachot that explains the source for citing it 3 times daily. However [this Beurei Hatefilah article](http://www.beureihatefila.com/files/Why_We_Recite_Ashrei_Three_Times_A_Day.pdf) cites several commentaries that state that it really should be cited **once** daily. I don't want to occupy space here pasting an excerpt, as it's tangential to the O.P.'s question.

*Pnei Yehoshua* on Brachot 4b says:

> Rabbi Eleazar said and Rabbi Avina said: Anyone who recites Psalm 145:
>   Tehila L’Dovod each day, three times per day, is promised a place in
>   the Next World. It appears that the intention of this rule is that if
>   one recites this prayer with the proper thought three times a day, it
>   becomes a Chazaka. His faith will be strengthened in his heart because
>   the whole world was created only so that we spend time learning Torah
>   that was written in the 22 letters of the Hebrew Alphabet that are in
>   this psalm. And everyone was created for that purpose. Three times a
>   day one should concentrate on the meaning of the verse: You open your
>   arms and feed all living beings. This means that G-d feeds his whole
>   world from the horns of the wild oxen to the eggs of the bugs. All of
>   them are nurtured with little effort and without pain as it is written
>   earlier in Psalm 145: The eyes of everything look to you and you give
>   each one his food at the right time. It follows from that rule that a
>   person should make his work secondary and his work for G-d primary as
>   our Sages taught us that those who follow that rule with have this and
>   that happen to them. This is also what is meant by the gemara’s
>   statement that he is guaranteed a place in the Next world. **Based on
>   this it is easy to understand why the three times that we recite
>   Ashrei are during the daytime and none are at night as part of
>   Maariv.** The reason is that the majority of time that a man spends in
>   his vocation is the time after the morning prayers, as it is written:
>   A person goes out to his work until evening meaning until after the
>   time to recite the afternoon prayer.

Answer (score 1):

As we see below from the OU the reason is that we do not have chazaras HaShatz (repetition of the Shmona Esrai) as part of Ma'ariv. As a result, there is no kedusha in the prayer. Thanks to @Lee for stating that this is based on the Maharsha.

[Ashrei](https://www.ou.org/community/tefilllah/ashrei/)

> It is evident that the Sages intended to link Ashrei with the reciting
>   of Kedusha, because Kedusha always follows Ashrei. The first Ashrei is
>   in Psukei Dezimra, which precedes the Kedusha of Et Sheim and the
>   Kedusha of Shemoneh Esreh, the second is before Uvah Letzion, the
>   final Kedushah of Shacharit, and the third starts the prayer of Mincha
>   which leads into the Amidah and Kedusha. Since Maariv does not contain
>   a Kedushah, we do not recite Ashrei then.

We can connect the three times we say Ashri (twice in Shacharis and once in Mincha) to the three times that we daven, but that is a different matter.

Comment: Why then isn't there an Ashrei during Mincha on Yom Kippur (Ashkenaz)? Or an Ashrei on Saturday nights at Maariv? The claim in that quote seems very non-evident to me.

Comment: @DoubleAA That is a good point that I had not thought of. This appears to be reasoning for the regular weekday davening. I would think that the Ashrei in Shacharis is after Shmonah Esrai and before the kedusha of uva letzion which is like the Ashrei of Neilah which follows immediately after mincha of Yom Kippur which runs into Neilah. The Ma'ariv Uva Letzion is part of Vihi Noam which is extra so would not need the Ashrei. However, this is a guess only. What I quoted was the only source I could find though it is from the OU.

Comment: The counterexamples noted by @DoubleAA seem strong; the example of _shacharis_, where one "_Ashre_" suffices for the first two _k'dusha_ recitals but not for the third, seems weak. But these questions are, I guess (I haven't yet followed the link), on the OU, not on you. +1 for an answer that cites an authority directly on point.

Comment: @msh210 Is a woman who happens to work for the OU an authority? (Unless you assume that everything she posts is from an OU rabbi, which very well could be, I suppose).

Comment: @Fred It seems she posts lots of things that aren't her own. (I don't know the provenance of the material in this post.) Also, I don't think her gender really matters

Comment: @Fred I meant the OU itself. Let's continue this in chat if you wish to continue it.

Comment: @DoubleAA I wasn't suggesting that her gender matters. I was suggesting that, for all I know, she is an arbitrary person (without any particular halachic authority so far as I know) whose job it is to post various things on the OU's site. Some of these things are links to shiurim by OU rabbis, some are announcements, and some are Torah tidbits with an unknown immediate origin. Does she write the posts herself? I don't know. But I do know that she didn't cite the source for the information in this answer.

Comment: @msh210 I don't know if some halachic authority ultimately supervises all Torah content posted on the OU site. Do you? If not, only sourced material or material known to be written by a known halachic authority would count as "cit[ing] an authority directly on the point." (You can move these comments to chat if you like. The "take extended discussion to chat" link hasn't popped up for me yet).

Comment: I believe this is taken from the Maharsha.

Answer (score 0):

The custom to recite Ashrei thrice daily seems to be based on the gemara in [Berachoth 4b](http://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.4b.46-47?lang=he&layout=block&sidebarLang=all)

> אמר רבי אלעזר א"ר אבינא: כל האומר "תהלה לדוד" בכל יום שלש פעמים מובטח לו שהוא בן העולם הבא
>
> R' Eleazar son of R' Abina said: Whoever recites "Tehilla l'David" three times
>   daily may be assured that he is a person of the world to come...

The only *tefilloth* (prayers) that are a *chova* (obligation) daily (at least originally when Maariv was still treated as a *tefilath reshuth* [optional prayer]) are *Shacharith* and *Mincha*. As such, these three recitals needed to be distributed between these two services.

(As far as why they were placed specifically where they are within these two services, [Ms. Farkas' suggestio](https://www.ou.org/community/tefilllah/ashrei/)n, cited in @SabbHillel's answer, regarding a juxtaposition to the following *Kedusha*s, sounds intriguing.)

Comment: Wouldn't you think that a Ben Olam HaBa would've been praying Maariv even back then? Also Kriat Shema at night was always obligatory so why not put it before Barchu there as it is before Barchu in the morning?

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm sure there are many bnei olam haba who never davened maariv in their lives (chasidei umos haolam come to mind). Further, if it were necessary to daven maariv to be a ben olam haba (and if Chazal felt that it was of such a level of importance) they could have made it obligatory.

Comment: @DoubleAA You're latter point though does indeed seem to suggest that it function's as part of the tefilla and not as of the Shema and its brachos (perhaps disassociating somewhat from the Farkasian theory).

Comment: we recite Ashrei 4 times during the period of S'lichot and there is no Kedusha anywhere in S'lichot.

Comment: @CashCow Perhaps the 13 Middoth are also a comparable reason...

Comment: Where do you see it is necessary to say Ashrei 3 times daily to be a Ben Olam haBa? The Talmud only claims the converse of that.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm obviously theorizing post-facto based on the practice. But it is in line with the sense of the talmudic text that it would have inspired those who instituted Ashrei as part of the traditional service to incorporate it into that which was obligatory and therefore more widely practiced. Someone who's motive is attaining olam haba is more likely to say Ashrei than Maariv based on this aggadic passage. Thus, Shacharith and Mincha are appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Rashi states that the 3 times are for the following:

> שלש פעמים - כנגד שלש תפלות.

According to Rashi, it would seem that you say ashrei in every teffilah.

Comment: but the two first are in shacharit

Comment: Please explain what you mean

Comment: According to Rashi, it would seem that you say ashrei in every teffilah.

Comment: It would behove anyone who has an opinion on this matter to explain Rashi.  Maybe many of the the scholars do not think that the Rashi is relevant. It would be interesting why these wise people who have such fine reputations on this platform feel this way. I think Rashi is very relevant. It is also interesting that none of the Rishonim ask a kashe on Rashi or disagree with Rashi.

Comment: It is also interesting that a contributor voted to have the Rashi deleted. In my wildest dream, I never would have suspected something like this. However, to give the person the benefit of the doubt, maybe he/she had another reason. Who knows? in my humble mind, as a minimum, Rashi, needs to be explained and not ignored.

Comment: I don't think it necessarily follows from Rashi that he thinks you should say Ashrei in the evening prayer. כנגד means "corresponding to," not "at the same time as"

Comment: Your inference from Rashi is an assumption. Rashi writes that the thrice daily corresponds to the three tefillos. You assume that if they correspond to the three tefillos, they should therefore be said during the three tefillos; this is not necessarily true.